# Search for key-value from array of nested hash in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I have array of nested hash that is,

```
@a = [{"id"=>"5", "head_id"=>nil,
         "children"=>
             [{"id"=>"19", "head_id"=>"5",
                 "children"=>
                     [{"id"=>"21", "head_id"=>"19", "children"=>[]}]},
             {"id"=>"20", "head_id"=>"5",
                 "children"=>
                     [{"id"=>"22", "head_id"=>"20", "children"=>[]}, {"id"=>"23"}]
             }]
     }]
```

I need array of all values which have key name 'id'. like @b = [5,19,21,20,22,23]
I have already try this '@a.find { |h| h['id']}`. 
Is anyone know how to get this?

Thanks.

Comment: This also works: `@a.to_s.scan(/(?<=\"id\"=>\")\d+/).map(&:to_i) #=> [5, 19, 21, 20, 22, 23]`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland great Its is working like charm. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create new method for `Array` class objects.

```
class Array
  def find_recursive_with arg, options = {}
    map do |e|
      first = e[arg]
      unless e[options[:nested]].blank?
        others = e[options[:nested]].find_recursive_with(arg, :nested => options[:nested])
      end
      [first] + (others || [])
    end.flatten.compact
  end
end
```

Using this method will be like

```
@a.find_recursive_with "id", :nested => "children"
```

Comment: I can't seem to find how does `map` work here. If you can give an explanation it would be nice.

Comment: plus one for the solution

Comment: `map` is similar to `each` difference is that `each` returns `array` on which you have called it, but `map` replace `e` element with last line in this example `[first] + (others || [])` will be replaced with every element in array. see also [Ruby map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-map)

Answer (score 4):

It can be done like this, using `recursion`

```
def traverse_hash
  values = []
  @a = [{"id"=>"5", "head_id"=>nil,
     "children"=>
         [{"id"=>"19", "head_id"=>"5",
             "children"=>
                 [{"id"=>"21", "head_id"=>"19", "children"=>[]}]},
         {"id"=>"20", "head_id"=>"5",
             "children"=>
                 [{"id"=>"22", "head_id"=>"20", "children"=>[]}, {"id"=>"23"}]
         }]
 }] 
 get_values(@a)
end

def get_values(array)   
  array.each do |hash|        
    hash.each do |key, value|
      (value.is_a?(Array) ? get_values(value) : (values << value)) if key.eql? 'id'
    end
  end    
end
```